# send data from raspberry pi to cordova app and vice versa

Tags: cordova, raspberry-pi3

I want code that will run on Raspberry pi constantly that will send me some sensor data to my Cordova android app. And also the code for sending the data to RPI from the Cordova app. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can host a server on your PI and use a generic client-server socket communication to transfer data. You can use any JavaScript library at the cordova end. ( Well, It runs on js )  and any other technology at the PI end.

You can use libraries like Socket.io, or pusher

https://socket.io/

https://pusher.com/docs/libraries

Note that pusher has a daily limit and some communication.

Hope this help. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used this plugin(https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) to connect with RPI. Now please tell me that can "bluetoothSerial.read()" and "bluetoothSerial.write()" able to communicate with RPI?

Comment: Yes. I've done a similar thing from Arduino. Since bluetooth is standard, that should work too. (You have to connect with the device ). Using wifi or internet would be easier in my opinion. ( plus you can connect more devices to the PI, no or less compatibility issues)

Comment: Ok..Let me try. I will let you know.